# Need to have 2d and 2dsphere indexes, but can't create those two indexes. Why?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

During a unit test on MongoDB geo data query, I get the following error message:

> can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { address.location: { $nearSphere: { x: -120.0, y: 47.0 }, $maxDistance: 0.01567855942887398 }, status: "INIT" }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { address.location: { $nearSphere: { x: -120.0, y: 47.0 }, $maxDistance: 0.01567855942887398 }, status: "INIT" }

After running the `createIndex` command, I however, get the following errors:

> db.store.createIndex({"address.location":"2d"})
>   location object expected, location array not in correct format
>   db.store.createIndex({"address.location":"2dsphere"})
>   Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ 47.399465, -122.2950165 ] }

The structure of the document data is the followings:

```
{
 ....
       "address" : {
           "street" : "Street One",
           "city" : "One City",
           "province" : "aProvince",
           "country" : "aCountry",
           "postalCode" : "91202",
           "location" : {
                   "type" : "Point",
                   "coordinates" : [
                           47.5891279,
                           -122.0446183
                   ]
           }
   }
```

What I do it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your "longitude" and "latitude" are in the reverse order, and the error should be telling you that a well ( as least in 3.x series it does ). You have  "latitude" and "longitude", so reverse it:

```js
{
   "address" : {
       "street" : "Street One",
       "city" : "One City",
       "province" : "aProvince",
       "country" : "aCountry",
       "postalCode" : "91202",
       "location" : {
           "type" : "Point",
           "coordinates" : [
               -122.0446183,
               47.5891279
           ]
       }
    }
}
```

And the index creates without error:

```js
db.store.ensureIndex({ "address.location": "2dsphere" })
```

That is for a ["2dsphere"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/) index. A ["2d"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2d-index/) index cannot be created on a [GeoJSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/) object, so you can only use the "coordinates" directly:

```js
db.store.ensureIndex({ "address.location.coordinates": "2d" })
```

It's "planar" so the GeoJSON format does not apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info. I have resolved the problem with the following steps: 1) upgrade to 3.0.4; 2) switch lat and lng; 3) run db.store.createIndex({"address.location.coordinates":"2dsphere"}) and db.store.createIndex({"address.location.coordinates":"2d"}).